# How do I get rid of this pointer in between Activities?

Tags: android

image of the offending pointer:
http://i842.photobucket.com/albums/zz347/oxygen_addict/bugs/device.png

the problem is that this pointer shows up whenever I transition from one activity to another.

code of the intent's:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this, test.app.com.ActivityOne.class);
startActivity(intent);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, test.app.com.ActivityTwo.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Manifest:

```
    <!-- LAUNCH ACTIVITY -->
    <activity android:name=".ActivityOne"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- SUB-ACTIVITIES -->
    <activity android:name=".ActivityTwo"
              android:launchMode="singleTop"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:noHistory="true"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```

Note:
within onCreate() of each activity I am using

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

How can I get rid of the pointer ?

Comment: What device are you testing this on? Your code looks fine to me - what happens if you comment out the bit which sets the fullscreen?

Comment: @Someone Somewhere: That is called a "mouse pointer". You will find it in most desktop-style operating systems with a graphical user interface ("GUI") written in the past thirty years or so. There is no mouse pointer in Android, since it is a touchscreen-based OS. To move the pointer from the emulator screen, move your mouse (or touchpad or trackball or whatever).

Comment: @CommonsWare made me chuckle.

Comment: @CommonsWare Actually, Android OS does have "mouse pointer". When I connect USB-mouse to my Chinese tablet with Android on it, I clearly see the pointer. :)

Comment: @GrAnd: Certain device manufacturers may have added it for their own devices.

Comment: LOL @ Commons. This mouse pointer is in the Android build I have running. Is there a way to hide it - possibly some application level command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: the OS has to be rebuilt to remove the pointer.
Would have been awesome to have an Application-level API available to control it....

Comment: UPDATE: it looks like our build of Android has animations between activities turned off. So when an animation should be showing (i.e. slide left) as an activity exits, the mouse cursor is shown instead. So what you see is: old Activity pops off, mouse cursor, new Activity pops on